# Await & thread safety in C# working with variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

Im using a MessageHandler class (inheriting from DelegatingHandler) in a web api 2 project

This is using the method:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Within this im using the following snippet:

```
string stringVariable = HelperClass.SomeFunctionThatReturnsAStringValue();
```

Further down the code i then make a call like so

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

Finally near the end i then do the following:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringVariable))
                response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue(Bearer, stringVariable));
```

I have set the below in the web.config which is also recommended from reading other SO posts.

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

My question is around the stringVariable.
Is it possible that this value would be set differently in the code snippet @ the end where its being sent back in response when multiple requests are coming in @ same time?

(my understanding is the processing thread gets released when await is called so thread safety could be an issue)

i.e.: for UserA the variable gets set but when UserB makes request @ same time the value set for UserA is applied to UserB because of the await logic

Comment: The thread will not be released until the `await` statement executes and each request will have its own `stringVaraible` as that is a local variable. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Ned, yes thats my understanding about await (the thread gets released), so what you are saying is stringVariable is safe in the above context and will always be set correctly for the thread it was used in?  (not get applied to a different thread from a different user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler creates a state machine for `async` methods which gets initialized separately for each thread that executes the method. So each request thread will have its own state machine and the thread itself will not be released until the `await` statement executes.

Each request will also have its own `stringVaraible` as that is a local variable it is not affected by other threads.

Comment: cool cool.. so the state machine will store any local variables within that meaning next time the thread is called (after it is released) everything is intact